# How to use $_POST without having to input a textfield

Tags: php, html, sql, ajax

I will summarize my goal using pseudocode and snippets in order to easily show what i would like to accomplish:

Table Column:

```
       <td data-target="scheduled">

         <?php
           if ($row['scheduled'] == 1) {
          ?>

          <a href="#" data-role="update" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>">YES</a>

         <?php
           } else if ($row['scheduled'] == 0) {
           ?>
          <a href="#" data-role="update" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>">NO</a>
         <?php
           }
          ?>
       </td>
```

This is a table column where the button depends on the value which is 1 (YES) and 0 (NO)

[image: sched]

Modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>UPDATE SCHEDULED?</label>
          <input type="text" id="scheduled" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="userId" class="form-control">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" id="save" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Update</a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

This modal pops up whenever the "YES" or "NO" buttons are clicked

[image: modal]

Right now I could change the text field into a 1 or 0 so that the output will show the corresponding result.

I am trying to get the "$scheduled = $_POST['scheduled'];" get the input automatically on click, the $_POST will become a 1 if the column is 0 and 0 if the column is 1.

Ajax:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

      $(document).on('click','a[data-role=update]',function(){
            var id  = $(this).data('id');
            var scheduled  = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=scheduled]').text();

            $('#scheduled').val(scheduled);
            $('#userId').val(id);
            $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
      });


       $('#save').click(function(){
          var id  = $('#userId').val();
          var scheduled = $('#scheduled').val();

          $.ajax({
              url      : 'connection.php',
              method   : 'post',
              data     : {scheduled: scheduled , id: id},
              success  : function(response){

                             $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=scheduled]').text(scheduled);
                             $('#myModal').modal('toggle');

                         }
          });
       });
  });
</script>
```

This is the current ajax code where it gets the value in the textfield.

SQL:

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])){

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $scheduled = $_POST['scheduled'];

    $result  = mysqli_query($connection , "UPDATE user SET scheduled = '$scheduled' WHERE id='$id'");
}
?>
```

The SQL code that updates the column with the help of ajax.

Summarizing with Pseudocode: (there will be no manual entry of a textfield, just a button straight to an update with ajax)

Modal:

```
 if ($row['scheduled'] == 1) {
    textfield input is 0
} else if ($row['scheduled'] == 0) {
    textfield input is 1
}
```

I think that if I can get that if statement in my modal to work, ajax and SQL will do the rest on the update and I will get a responsive button that changes text (YES or NO).

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm a little lost at what you're trying to achieve. Can you summarise the user flow? ("I want the user to click on X and then Y happens...")

Comment: I want the user to click on the Scheduled column (the "YES" or "NO") then the value changes to the other using ajax and SQL update

Answer (score 0):

As the question used pseudocode snippets the use of pseudocode snippets to answer would seem appropriate - it should, possibly help.

It is very easy to toggle the state of an item , the use of `dataset` attributes help greatly with such as task and I see that you are making use of them already so this should be easy. If the state of an item is `1` then to toggle the state it is simply `1 minus current state`

An example

```
    <a href='#' data-scheduled=1 data-id=303 data-role='update'>Yes</a>
    <a href='#' data-scheduled=1 data-id=404 data-role='update'>Yes</a>
    <a href='#' data-scheduled=1 data-id=505 data-role='update'>Yes</a>

<script>
    let links=Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('a[data-scheduled]') );
    let matrix={
        1:'YES',
        0:'NO'
    }
        links.forEach( a=>{
            a.addEventListener('click', e=>{
                /* Toggle the state of the link */
                e.target.dataset.scheduled = 1 - parseInt( e.target.dataset.scheduled );
                e.target.textContent=matrix[ e.target.dataset.scheduled ];
                alert( 'send ajax request using '+e.target.dataset.scheduled+' as the value for button/link of id '+e.target.dataset.id )
            })
        })
</script>
```

Clicking each link will change the dataset attribute `scheduled` to either 1 or 0 - a lookup into the text matrix using that value is used to set the text of the link accordingly. The example will use an `alert` but you will want to send an ajax request at that point.

Upon initial page load you would set the value of `data-scheduled` based upon database values so that the initial state is not necessarily always 1. You can, I'm sure, figure how to alter the logic appropriately to set either `YES` or `NO` for each link at pageload... `$text=$row['scheduled']==1 ? 'YES' : 'NO';` etc

Hope it helps.

full example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>toggle state</title>
        <style>
            body{font-family:calibri,verdana,arial;}
            *{box-sizing:border-box;}
            [data-scheduled]{margin:0.5rem;padding:0.25rem;border:1px solid rgba(133,133,133,0.25);}
            [data-scheduled="0"]{background:rgba(255,0,0,0.1)}
            [data-scheduled="1"]{background:rgba(0,255,0,0.1)}
        </style>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e=>{
                let links=Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('a[data-scheduled]') );
                let matrix={
                    1:'YES',
                    0:'NO'
                }
                links.forEach( a=>{
                    a.addEventListener('click', e=>{
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.target.dataset.scheduled = 1 - parseInt( e.target.dataset.scheduled );
                        e.target.textContent=matrix[ e.target.dataset.scheduled ];
                        console.info('send ajax request using '+e.target.dataset.scheduled+' as the value ( or "'+matrix[ e.target.dataset.scheduled ]+'" )for button/link of id '+e.target.dataset.id);
                    })
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            for( $i=1; $i <= 25; $i++ ){

                $scheduled=rand(0,1);
                $text=$scheduled==1 ? 'YES' : 'NO';

                printf(
                    '<a href="#" data-scheduled=%d data-id=%d data-role="update">%s</a>',
                    $scheduled,
                    $i,
                    $text
                );
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I get the concept of the example but i am not sure how it is going to connect to my SQL table column "scheduled".

Comment: your page does a db lookup at page load so use the recordset to help build the appropriate html structure?